# How can I have Spring Data JPA keep the connection open without a transaction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot 3.0 application that gets a Blob from a Spring Data repository:

```
@Service
public class CarService {

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    public Set<CarDto> getValuations(LocalDate date) {          
        Blob reportData = carRepository.getReportData("sedan,truck", date);
        try {
            byte[] b= reportData.getBytes(1, (int) reportData.length());
            log.debug("connection is closed by Spring Data JPA");
            //...
        } 

public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Car, Long> {
    
    @Procedure(value="pValuation", outputParameterName="reportData")
    Blob getReportData(String carTypes, LocalDate tradeDate);
```

Unfortunately, Spring Data closes the connection after returning the `Blob` from the `getReportData` method. This results in the following error when I try to get the bytes from the `Blob`:

> SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed. The connection is closed.

I can keep the connection open by making `getValuations` transactional (i.e., annotation the method as `@Transactional`), but then the database hangs because of locking issues.

How can I tell Spring Data to keep the connection open without a transaction so I can retrieve bytes from the Blob?

*Note: I cannot use byte[] as the return type of `getReportData` since the data will be truncated at 8000 bytes.*

*Note: My procedure, `pValuation`, is read only.*

**Update**

I can call this stored procedure without using Spring Data JPA (and without a transaction) as follows:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CarService {
  
    private final CarRepository carRepository;
    private final EntityManager em;

    public Set<CarDto> getValuations(LocalDate date) {
        
        StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("pValuation");
        q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("carTypes", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("tradeDate", LocalDate.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportData", Blob.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        q.setParameter("carTypes", "sedan,truck");
        q.setParameter("tradeDate", date);
        q.execute();
        
        Blob reportData = (Blob) q.getOutputParameterValue("reportData");
        
        log.debug("got Blob");
        try {
            byte[] b= reportData.getBytes(1, (int) reportData.length());
            log.debug("got bytes");
            return carRepository.getCarValuations(b);
        } 
        catch (SQLException convertBlobToBytesException) {
                log.error(convertBlobToBytesException.toString());
        }
    }
```

This code works because the connection stays open while reading the bytes. From what I can tell, Spring Data closes the connection after the repository method call unless I have a transaction (which I can't use b/c the DB SP hangs).

Comment: You really should be using `@Transactional` and make it readonly in this case. What I find weird is that when using a `byte[]` the value is truncated because in the end it all ends up in e `Blob` any way.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, the stored procedure on the DB will hang if I run it using `@Transactional`. The stored procedure was written by a 3rd party vendor and I can't change it. By the way I can successfully call the stored procedure without a transaction and without using Spring Data. I'll post this code but I would like to use Spring Data.

Comment: If you can call it with plain JDBC, what is the added benefit of adding JPA on top of that?

Comment: @M.Deinum - I think two benefits of using Spring Data JPA over the JPA code posted above (or plain JDBC) are 1) The code is less verbose with Spring Data JPA and will be easier to maintain. 2) The rest of my code base is using Spring Data JPA. By using Spring Data JPA for this SP, it will keep the code more consistent and easier to maintain.

Comment: Using a `SimpleJdbcCall` or just `JdbcTemplate.call`/`JdbcTemplate.execute` isn't  anymore complex, with the benefit that it is executed within the current connection. I find it weird the the procedure hangs when it is in a transaction, seems like a flaw/fault/bug in the SP. It isn't Spring Data that is closing the connection, that is the default behavior when there is no transaction (or rather being closes at the end of the transaction which is very small here).

Comment: @M.Deinum - Yes, I agree with your comment on the SP having an issue. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the SP. It makes sense that the connection would be closed w/ no txn by default after the end of Spring Data repo call. What's odd is that my code worked with Spring Boot 2.3 and the MSSQL JDBC 8.2.2.jre8. At any rate, I don't think I have much of a choice due to the faulty SP. Thanks for pointing out `SimpleJdbcCall`. I'll use that as like you said it isn't anymore complex. If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept and upvote. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Have you tried keeping the same driver version instead of the newer one? Might be related to the driver then. Spring is nothing more then a wrapper on those technologies (although Hibernate does add some additional layers on top of that).

Comment: That's a good idea. I haven't tried it though because I migrated the project from Java 8 to Java 17 when upgrading Spring Boot 3. Microsoft doesn't have the old driver version using Java 17, so I'd need to revert the project back to Java 8. I may try to do this after I complete my current upgrade project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `EntityManager` with the `createStoredProcedureQuery` you might take a look at the [`SimpleJdbcCall`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html). The API is quite similar and you could define it once (as a bean or in the constructor) and re-use the definition. The added benefit is that the callback to extract the result is operating on the current connection so it stays open.

Spring Boot automatically configures a `JdbcTemplate` which you can re-use to create a `SimpleJdbcCall`.

```java
SimpleJdbcCall sp = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
sp.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("carTypes", Types.VARCHAR),
new SqlParameter("tradeDate", Types.DATE), new SqlOutParameter("reportData", Types.BLOB, (rs, row) -> { Blob blob = rs.getBlob("reportData"); return blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());})


sp.executeObject(byte[].class, "sedan,truck", date);
```

Something along these lines should work. Not sure if the code is totally fine as I coded it from the top of my head.